# Using custom script files with C++ project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

### TL;DR

1. My project uses a custom script file at runtime.
2. My project builds fine in VS and runs on the command line.
3. However when running in VS an error is thrown implying the file doesn't exist.

### Full Details

My c++ project uses a custom scripting file to apply some settings at run time:

- these are javascript like but not actual javascript
- having these settings not in compiled files means they may be changed without recompiling
  Everything builds fine, the script is copied using xcopy in a post build event.

When running in VS2019 it doesn't *seem* to be able to find the scripting file.
An opaque, library specific error is issued:  `A GenApi error has occurred`

But when running the resulting .exe **from cmd everything works**, the script is used no problem.
If the script file is removed from the output dir and the .exe is run again I get the same `A GenApi error has occurred`.

#### I have tried:

- running in release and debug.
- including and excluding the file from the build.

I don't want to debug the script, I just need it to be used during start up so I can debug the rest of the program which is in C++.....

#### Example Code

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <EGrabber.h>

void configure() {
    Euresys::EGenTL gentl;
    Euresys::EGrabber<> grabber(gentl);
    grabber.runScript("config.js");
}

int main() {
    try {
        configure();
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**config.js**

```
var grabber = grabbers[0];
var FPS = 150;
// camera configuration
grabber.RemotePort.set("TriggerMode", "On");
grabber.RemotePort.set("TriggerSource", "CXPin");
grabber.RemotePort.set("ExposureMode", "TriggerWidth");
// frame grabber configuration
grabber.DevicePort.set("CameraControlMethod", "RG");
grabber.DevicePort.set("CycleTriggerSource", "Immediate");
grabber.DevicePort.set("CycleMinimumPeriod", 1e6 / FPS);
```

#### More info:

#### [script documentation](https://documentation.euresys.com/Products/Coaxlink/Coaxlink_10_1/Content/coaxlink/programmers-guide/docbasics.js.htm)

Comment: as mentioned I have tried this, it doesn't seem to make any difference. The problem isn't excluding from the build but more including at runtime

Comment: Different current working directory when you run from VS and when you run from command line. When run from VS the current working directory is the project directory not the output directory.

Comment: @john it seems you are correct. I have added the full path to the script and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on @john 's comment:

There is a **different current working directory** when running from *VS* and when running from the *command line*.

When run from *VS* the *current working directory* is the *project directory* not the output directory.

The script was in `project-dir\src` not the immediate project dir.

**Moving the script up to the project directory solved everything.**

---

#### Alternative solutions, which worked:

1. Use the full path: `C:\\full\\path\\config.js`

(the application startup path can be extracted from argv[0])

2. Change the debug working directory in VS:

   - Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Working Directory
   - Enter output path, eg: $(SolutionDir)bin$(Platform)$(Configuration)\

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.